# Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred on Content and Structure log

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, edit, links

Getting error when clicking on Content and Structure log.

Also getting same error on below one.

In Edit mode of page, when i trying to add link, I am getting following error.

[image]

[image]

Things I tried,

1) checked log for generated correlation id, nothing found.

2) checked event log and getting error related "App state update".

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: there must be something with the co realtion id. At what point it throws error... please check that. clear cache and edit in new window. and check in developer tool in Network tab if any where anything is logged

Comment: did you try to choose second option, From address? If it doesn't give you an error, insert SharePoint link in and you are good.

Comment: @AnkitKumar I have searched correlation id in sharepoint log, but nothing found related. And there no error coming on console also.

Comment: @DaniloKorac, 2nd option , From address is working

Comment: Even also Content and Structure log is also not working, giving same error

Comment: It wont come in console. Go to Network tab. There is green button to record. click on it and reload the page. then click on the content and structure log and check all the response you are getting in the network tab. Check for row with 400 code. click on it and check more details in response header

Comment: State update may be related to the SharePoint page state like edit mode, display mode. have you enabled session state in the site collection?

Comment: @AnkitKumar checked in Network tab, Every row has status 200 OK

Comment: Do one thing.. restart the server.. refresh and restart SharePoint Administrator services and SharePoint Timer services and an IIS reset and then check

Comment: restarted the server, restarted SharePoint Administrator services and SharePoint Timer services and an IIS reset. Still same error

Comment: When I was checking log, I found that few lists are corrupted and unable to open list setting page

Comment: Thanks @AnkitKumar, Danilo and Raghavendra. you guys are great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved.

Filtered log message with list and failed and checked for below kind of error,

> [STS3::COWSList::GetList] Initialize failed. Return error to caller,
>   URL =
>   sts4://url/siteurl=/siteid={b0485081-a7c0-4029-8009-9c2c38513815}/weburl=/webid={123f3c8c-5a2a-42e9-acbd-bfb67b8084f7}/listid={b4c8bf79-183e-450d-8308-43550697ab51} hr=80642616  [sts3util.cxx:5723] 
>   search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3util.cxx

After that i verified given list id i.e

> b4c8bf79-183e-450d-8308-43550697ab51

from application and found out that library setting page of that list was failed to open and throw error.

Finally I came on conclusion that this list has been corrupted and need to delete and recreate again.

After deleting, everything started working.
Hurray :-)

Comment: There is always something in co-relation id. Good job!!